# NSIS terms of use

Tags: licensing, nsis

Can anyone explain to me what does the NSIS licensing terms mean? http://nsis.sourceforge.net/License

So far it seems that the system is usable in commercial products, but the ZLIB/PNG/BZIP2/LZMA/CPL1.0 part confuses me.

Do I have to include a license page with all these licenses in setup that user has to agree with? Or are they for source code modifications only? Or only if you're compressing the data with one of the libraries?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSIS is a **"software"** application. The license information provided in the license page describes "use, distribution, modification" cases for **NSIS itself**. Since you are not distributing "NSIS" but an output file (installer for your application) that is produced by NSIS, you **shouldn't** include those licenses in your application (and installer).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to display a nsis specific license in a normal installer (Except if your installer includes the nsis sourcecode I guess)

Everything except the bzip2 and lzma compression is ZLIB/PNG and this is a very open and nice license (This includes the content on the wiki unless stated otherwise IIRC). Unless you are distributing modified versions on nsis itself you probably don't have anything to worry about. (And of course, [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL) & TINLA)